# Regular expression for a list of items separated by comma or by comma and a space

Tags: regex

Hey,
I can't figure out how to write a regular expression for my website, I would like to let the user input a list of items (tags) separated by comma or by comma and a space, for example "apple, pie,applepie". Would it be possible to have such regexp?
Thanks!

EDIT:
I would like a regexp for javascript in order to check the input before the user submits a form.

Comment: Almost any language has simple `string.split` operations for that, what language do you use for this? Easy to combine with a `string.replace` or a `string.trim`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried JavaScript `string.split(',')` method?

Comment: What would an illegal input to your textbox look like?

Comment: I would do it with a "split by regular expression" if you have this possibility, like this `string.split(new RegExp('([ ]*[\,][ ]*)+'))`

Answer (score 49, accepted):

What you're looking for is deceptively easy:

```
[^,]+
```

This will give you every comma-separated token, and will exclude empty tokens (if the user enters "a,,b" you will only get 'a' and 'b'), BUT it will break if they enter "a,  ,b".

If you want to strip the spaces from either side properly (and exclude whitespace only elements), then it gets a tiny bit more complicated:

```
[^,\s][^\,]*[^,\s]*
```

However, as has been mentioned in some of the comments, why do you need a regex where a simple split and trim will do the trick?

Comment: I just need to check that in javascript, then I will do the explode / trim trick in PHP to get out the array of items :) thanks anyway!

Comment: By the way, in javascript would this do the trick: new RegExp(/[^,]+/); ?

Comment: It should do, but you should be able to simplify it to `"apple, pie,applepie".match(/[^,]+/g);` Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/SD6Bt/

Comment: The 'g' is necessary to tell it to match as many times as it can.

Comment: The more complicated solution is not trimming the ending space: https://jsfiddle.net/2k9or1b7/2/

Comment: I do not think this is correct. Try "cat, dog , ant( elephant  , lion(tiger)), bird"  input and one element will be "elephant  ". So the spaces after the match are not skipped.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the words in your list may be letters from a to z and you allow, but do not require, a space after the comma separators, your reg exp would be
[a-z]+(,\s*[a-z]+)*

This is match "ab" or "ab, de", but not "ab ,dc"

Comment: This requires repeating the pattern (two times `[a-z]`)

Comment: The result of `http://www.example.com'.match(/[a-z]+(,\s*[a-z]+)*/g)`:
`["https", "www", "example", "com"]`

Answer (score 5):

I often work with coma separated pattern, and for me, this works :

```
((^|[,])pattern)+
```

where "pattern" is the single element regexp

Comment: I like the idea for complex pattern you don't want to repeat: `^(?!,)((^|, ?)pattern)+$` allows to check for a coma or coma space separated list of `pattern`. This should be equivalent to `^pattern(, ?pattern)*`

Answer (score 4):

This thread is almost 7 years old and was last active 5 months ago, but I wanted to achieve the same results as OP and after reading this thread, came across a nifty solution that seems to work well

```
.match(/[^,\s?]+/g)
```

Here's an image with some example code of how I'm using it and how it's working

[image]

Regarding the regular expression... I suppose a more accurate statement would be to say "target anything that IS NOT a comma followed by any (optional) amount of white space" ?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simpler solution:

```js
    console.log("test, , test".match(/[^,(?! )]+/g));
```

It doesn't break on empty properties and strips spaces before and after properties.

Comment: ah yes the all too underappreciated negative lookahead

Comment: If it ain't broken ;)

Answer (score 2):

This might work:

```
([^,]*)(, ?([^,]*))*
```

Comment: You should anchor this, otherwise it will always match any string since the entire expression is optional.

Answer (score 2):

I needed an strict validation for a comma separated input alphabetic characters, no spaces. I end up using this one is case anyone needed:

```
/^[a-z]+(,[a-z]+)*$/
```

Or, to support lower- and uppercase words:

```
/^[A-Za-z]+(?:,[A-Za-z]+)*$/
```

In case one need to allow whitespace between words:

```
/^[A-Za-z]+(?:\s*,\s*[A-Za-z]+)*$/
/^[A-Za-z]+(?:,\s*[A-Za-z]+)*$/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
([^,]*)
```

Look For Commas within a given string, followed by separating these. in regards to the whitespace? cant you just use commas? remove whitespace?

Answer (score 0):

My two cents: assuming we have $NATURAL_REGEX in comma separated list for me works (tested in bash)

```
^($NATURAL_REGEX+(,$NATURAL_REGEX+)*)+$
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this, it worked for me:

```
/.+?[\|$]/g
```

or

```
/[^\|?]+/g
```

but replace `'|'` for the one you need. Also, don't forget about shielding.

Answer (score -10):

something like this should work: `((apple|pie|applepie),\s?)*`