# Invalid regular expression in HTML5 input pattern

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I need to use this regular expression in a HTML input (taken from [Regular expression for a list of items separated by comma or by comma and a space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001554/regular-expression-for-a-list-of-items-separated-by-comma-or-by-comma-and-a-spac)):

```
[^,\s][^\,]*[^,\s]*
```

So I set it in an input:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="input" name="input" data-ng-model="myModel" pattern="[^,\s][^\,]*[^,\s]*">
```

But I get this error in console:

```
Pattern attribute value [^,\s][^\,]*[^,\s]* is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /[^,\s][^\,]*[^,\s]*/: Invalid escape
```

What is wrong with that regex?

I'm using Angular 1.5 BTW.

Comment: Invalid escape before ","

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the escaping backslash from before the comma and use

```
 pattern="[^,\s][^,]*[^,\s]*"
```

It is necessary since FF and Chrome compile the `pattern` regex using the ES6 regex syntax specifications, and use the `/u` modifier when compiling the RegExp object. This lays certain restrictions on the pattern. In this case, a regular symbol, not a special metacharacter, a comma, was escaped inside a character class. Thus, removing the escape solves the issue.

```css
input:valid {
  color: black;
  border: 5px solid #dadadada;
  border-radius: 7px;
}
input:invalid {
  color: navy;
  outline: none; 
  border-color: #ff1050;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input" name="input" data-ng-model="myModel" pattern="[^,\s][^,]*[^,\s]*">
</form>
```