# Wrong pattern for html text inputs

Tags: html, regex, firefox

In the Firefox console (no message for Chrome). I got this error :

> Unable to check < input pattern = '[^? <> |?!; = \,;:] *' > Because the pattern is not a valid regular expression: invalid identity escape in regular expression

I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36953775/firefox-error-unable-to-check-input-because-the-pattern-is-not-a-valid-regexp) but it does not seem to be the same case.

I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43071450/invalid-regular-expression-in-html5-input-pattern) but in my case I have to keep the backslash in my pattern to avoid an antislash insert from the users.

I checked my pattern on https://regex101.com/ and it seem to be all right.

That happens for `[^?<>|?!;=\,;:]*` and `[^?<>|?;=\]*`.

Someone has got an idea ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid regular expression in HTML5 input pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43071450/invalid-regular-expression-in-html5-input-pattern)

Comment: You should not escape commas in a regex compiled with `u`  modifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem for Firefox is the backslash. To resolve this problem you must escape the backslash with another one like this : `[^<>|?!=\\,;:]*`